# Add item to cart (React-router / Redux)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-router

I'm trying to complete my first big assignment for school where I need to use react-router and redux. I'm at the last page/component but have been completely stuck for the past 2 days. The app is an app to order coffee. I have a menu page/component, to which I added my menu items with a .map of a json file for an 'items' component. I now need to be able to add my items onClick to the cart component but I can't figure out how.

I had thought of maybe saving either the whole needed data of the item to an empty array, which then I would push to my cart component and then map all the info for a new component to generate the cart items. But after 2 days of failed attempts, I just now managed within the 'items' component to create a 'inCart' state that saves an array with the 2 pieces of info I need for my cart.

There still are 2 issues though:

1. on the first click nothing gets saved, but its only after the second click that the items show up in my array.
2. because the state is created within the 'items' component which then is mapped, my state is also connected to only one item at a time, so if I click on 2 different types of coffee, these won't end up in the same array.

I get the feeling that maybe redux would be the way to go in this case, but as I'm very new at it, I can't quite wrap my head around how that would be implemented in this case.

Overall what I find is making it hard for me to find a solution is the fact that the button I need my onClick function to work with is inside the 'items' component while I would need a state with my array to be in my 'menu' component, in order to record all different types of coffee chosen. That's why I'm thinking Redux would maybe be the solution, but not sure how to implement it.

Any types of suggestions that would put me in the right direction to get this problem solved are warmly welcome!!

Following are my 'menu' component and 'item' component code to clarify where I'm at right now.

MENU COMPONENT:

```
    const Menu = () => {
        let items = require('../assets/menu.json');
        let counter = useSelector(state => state.cartCounter);
        const dispatch = useDispatch();
        const showNav = useSelector(state => state.toggleNav);
        const showCart = useSelector(state => state.toggleCart);
 
        if (showNav){
            return ( <Nav /> )
        } else {
            return (
            <section className='menu'>
                {showCart ? <Cart /> : ''}
                <header>
                        <section className='nav' onClick={() => dispatch(toggleNav())}>
                            <div ></div>
                            <div></div>
                            <div></div> 
                        </section>
                        <section onClick={() => dispatch(toggleCart())}>
                            <img src={bag} alt='bag' className='bag'></img>
                            <p className='cart-counter'>{counter}</p>
                        </section>
                </header>
                <h1>Meny</h1>
                {items.map((item, index) => <Item key={index} data={item}/>)}                
            </section>
        )}
    }
    export default Menu;
```

```
ITEM COMPONENT:
    const Item = (props) => {
        const dispatch = useDispatch();
        let [inCart, setInCart] = useState([]);
        const updateInCart=  (e)  => {
            setInCart([
              ...inCart,
              {
                title: props.data.title,
                price: props.data.price,
              }
            ]);
          };
     
        const onClick = (e) => {
            dispatch(cartIncrement());
            updateInCart();
            console.log(inCart) 
        } 

        return ( 
            <section className='item-container'>
                <img src={add} alt='add' className='add-cart' onClick={onClick}></img>
                <article className='item-text'>
                <section className='first-line'>
                    <h2 >{props.data.title}</h2>
                    <h2 className='price'>{props.data.price} kr</h2>
                </section>
                <p className='beans'>{props.data.beans}</p>
                </article>
            </section>
        );
    }
     
    export default Item;
```

Comment: You don't need Redux.  You just need to move the cart state up from the `Item` component to the `Menu` component.  Create an `addToCart` callback in `Menu` and pass it as a prop to `Item`.  Check out the docs on [Lifting State Up](https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html).

Comment: I looked into it and tried implementing, but I can't get it to work. I can't find any example of lifting states in functional components, but just class components. Is there a way to lift in functional components as well or would I need to change it to a class one?

Comment: You probably don't find a lot of sources, because there is no real difference between class  & function components there. It's just `useState` in function components and `setState` in class components, but apart from that API difference, everything works exactly the same.